# How to get the dynamic calendar value input

Tags: jsf-2

I wanted to write a code to get the input value of prime faces calendar input value.

```
<div style="padding-left: 300px;">
    <p:calendar value="#{calendarBean.fromDate}" id="fromButton" showOn="button" pattern="dd-MMMM-yyyy" 
                                    required="true" requiredMessage="Insert From Date!">
    </p:calendar>
    <p:calendar value="#{calendarBean.toDate}" id="toButton" showOn="button" pattern="dd-MMMM-yyyy"
                                    style="padding-left: 100px;padding-right: 30px" required="true" requiredMessage="Insert To Date!">
    </p:calendar>
    <p:commandButton actionListener="#{userLeaveBean.addAppliedLeave}" styleClass="apply_button" value="Create Leave">
    <f:attribute name="userId" value="#{employee.name}"/>
    </p:commandButton>
</div>
```

I want to pass three parameter values(userId,fromDate,toDate) through the method call

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{userLeaveBean.addAppliedLeave}" styleClass="apply_button" value="Create Leave">
```

using method addAppliedLeave().
I am able to send the userId using:

```
<f:attribute name="userId" value="#{employee.name}"/> but how can I pass the values for calender input at run time?
```

also I am able to get the value of userId in method addAppliedLeave()

```
public void addAppliedLeave(ActionEvent event){

    String userId = (String)event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("userId");
    System.out.println(userId);
    String fromDate = (String)event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("fromDate");
    System.out.println(fromDate);

    }
```

but I am totaly helpless about dynamic input of `<p:calendar>` value.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily get `p:calender` value at run time using `p:ajax` as shown here

```
/* view.xhtml  */

<p:calendar value="#{yourBackingBean.user.fromDate}" mode="inline" id="inlineCal">  
        <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{yourBackingBean.handleDateSelect}" update="growl" />  
    </p:calendar>
```

/* Backing bean  */

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class YourBackingBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

     private User user;



    public void handleDateSelect(DateSelectEvent event) {

    System.out.println("dynamic date selected is "+user.getFromDate());

    // so here you will get everytime your changed date.
    //As this method will get called everytime whenever you will change your date from p:calender component.



    }


      public User getUser() {

     if(user==null){

     user=new User();

     }

     return user;
    }


}
```

/* javaBean */

```
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


     private Date fromDate;
     private Date toDate;

    public Date getFromDate() {
        return fromDate;
    }

    public void setFromDate(Date fromDate) {
        this.fromDate = fromDate;
    }

    public Date getToDate() {
        return toDate;
    }

    public void setToDate(Date toDate) {
        this.toDate = toDate;
    }


}
```

Comment: What is Register()? Did you mean that as the Constructor of YourBackingBean class? Even if I do it, it gives null when I select date from the datepicker Calendar.

Comment: `@ManagedBean (name = "userLeaveBean")
@ViewScoped
public class AddLeaveDetails {
 
 
 private CalendarBean dateObject;
 public CalendarBean getDateObject() {
  
  if(dateObject == null){
   
   dateObject = new CalendarBean();
  }
  return dateObject;
 }
}` thats in my Bean

Comment: and `<p:calendar value="#{userLeaveBean.dateObject.fromDate}" id="fromButton" showOn="button" pattern="dd-MMMM-yyyy" 
          required="true" requiredMessage="Insert From Date!">
      <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{userLeaveBean.handleDateSelect}" process="@this"/>
     </p:calendar>`

Comment: `public void handleDateSelect(DateSelectEvent event){
  
  Date date = event.getDate();
  System.out.println("Dynamic Value :: "+date);
  System.out.println("Value :: "+dateObject.getFromDate());
 }` here both the Print statement gives null in console

Comment: You code is working . I am getting calender value correctly. Your both `sysout` values are displaying proper results.

Comment: but it does not work for me..even I created new test.xhtml page and did the same code to understand whether I had problem with other related codes or not..but results same!

Comment: Hi Ran..it was correct from the very begining..but the <p:calendar> code was not within <h:form> tag. After i put that within the <h:form> tag it worked fine.. :)
Thanks so much for your help..:)